# FCM - Upgrading service worker code to Firebase 9

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

The [FCM doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/topic-messaging#setting_notification_options_in_the_service_worker) shows how to handle background messages with Firebase 9 but the examples for Firebase 9 uses `import` which as far as I understand is not supported in service workers. The Firebase 8 example correctly uses `ImportScripts`.

I have tried using `ImportScripts` for Firebase 9:

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.2/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.2/firebase-messaging.js');
```

Both paths exist, but in my app I get an error

> The script at
> 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.2/firebase-app.js' failed to
> load.

Can anyone show some code of a working version of a service worker using Firebase 9 to handle background message?

Note: the [doc on how to add Firebase to a web project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/learn-more#libraries-hosting-urls) says

> Reserved Hosting URLs are available only with version 8 and earlier.
> You cannot use version 9 or later with Hosting URLs.

Which would explain why the `ImportScripts` doesn't work but how to proceed then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following imports:

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.5.0/firebase-app-compat.js')
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.5.0/firebase-messaging-compat.js')
```

These are compatibility versions of v9 which should support the other existing code within the file.

Comment: Ok, but what if I want to upgrade to the new version of the SDK? The compat version wont be supported forever....

Comment: Won't be supported forever but I'm just gonna have to make use of this for the time being haha.